# How to json decode a multi dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have an array which contain JSON in some index which i have to decode it

***For Example:***

**This is JSON**

```
$json = {"Lavel1":"This is Lavel1","LavelLoop":"{\"Lavel2\":\"This is Lavel2\",\"LavelLoop\":\"{\\\"Lavel3\\\":\\\"This is Lavel3\\\",\\\"LavelLoop\\\":[]}\"}"}
```

**If is decode it first time then it give this array**

```
$array = json_decode($json);

// this is the output 
Array
(
    [Lavel1] => This is Lavel1
    [LavelLoop] => {"Lavel2":"This is Lavel2","LavelLoop":"{\"Lavel3\":\"This is Lavel3\",\"LavelLoop\":[]}"}
)
```

**So i have decode it three times but i can't assume how many sub json it contain**

> **Desire output should be like this**

```
Array
(
    [Lavel1] => This is Lavel1
    [LavelLoop] => Array
        (
            [Lavel2] => This is Lavel2
            [LavelLoop] => Array
                (
                    [Lavel3] => This is Lavel3
                    [LavelLoop] => Array
                        (
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

I have tried loop but it not working it giving me bug like some index shown me empty

Comment: `$result = json_decode('<multi-dimensional-array>', true);`

Comment: have you tried this because i knew this function but the json contain it self a sub json

Comment: i have updated the question have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated the answer have a look again

```
$json = '{"Lavel1":"This is Lavel1","LavelLoop":"{\"Lavel2\":\"This is Lavel2\",\"LavelLoop\":\"{\\\"Lavel3\\\":\\\"This is Lavel3\\\",\\\"LavelLoop\\\":[]}\"}"}';

$array = nested_jsonDecode($json, true);

print_r($array);


function nested_jsonDecode($string, $is_array = true){
    return is_bool($is_array) 
        ? json_decode(str_replace(['\\','"[',']"','"{', '}"'], ['','[',']','{', '}'],$string), $is_array)
        : '';
}
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [Lavel1] => This is Lavel1
    [LavelLoop] => Array
        (
            [Lavel2] => This is Lavel2
            [LavelLoop] => Array
                (
                    [Lavel3] => This is Lavel3
                    [LavelLoop] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

`LaravelLoop` is a string, not an object. It's like that for all of them. Remove the quotes and it will decode fine.

Comment: yes you are right it is JSON. and i have to decode it too even into that lavelLoop contain the same

Comment: you may not have seen json string properly see this first if you remove the quote the json may be break and after decode result will null or false

Comment: It's bunch of json objects that have quotes around them. That causes them to be string, hence why everyone is above is using json_decode a bunch of times. Instead of being nested objects, it's a bunch of nested strings. Remove pairs of quotes and you'll only need one json_decode call